# Selenium is not accessing drivers properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to access a browser using Selenium.

My first Python code try is this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

It gives me the error message:

```
'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Some other answers on here suggest I point to the path manually.  So I try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chromedriver_loc = '/usr/local/bin'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_loc)
```

This gives me the error message:

```
'bin' executable may have wrong permissions.
```

I am using a Mac and running an Anaconda Spyder environment.

The chromedriver file is in the /usr/local/bin.  When I use GetInfo from the Finder program, the 'locked' selection is unchecked, but grayed out so I can't check or uncheck it.

The same error messages appear if I substitute Firefox for Chrome.

Can anybody help me provide the right 'permissions' so I can properly use Selenium?  Please let me know if you need additional information, as this is my first question on here.

Comment: Try `chromedriver_loc = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'`

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I assumed that by location, they meant the subdirectory, not the actual file itself.  Doh!

Comment: Good to head that it helped! I added an answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the full path including the filename:

```
chromedriver_loc = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
```